# Using ionic push in production

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework

If I Use `dev_push:false` then can I use  same ionic push code in my app for production.

Please do let me know I am confused .

```
  $ionicAppProvider.identify({
    app_id: 'a61bddd',
    api_key: '9fdb9a4b3axxxxxxxxa33419463269yyyyyyyc2d6',
    gcm_id: '5529cccccwa',
    dev_push: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But make sure you have created and uploaded certificates for ISO/Android to ionic push server.

You can follow step by step certification creation for [ios](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-ios-setup) and [android](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-android-setup) in ionic documentation. Once you successfully upload those certificates you can receive actual push notification using your same code.